# Issues with syncing deployed Vue app on Netlify

Tags: vue.js, netlify

I'm trying to build an app using Vue and I hosted it on Netlify so I can show it to my instructors. I have now made some changes to my Github repo but it is not updated on Netlify. Do I have to redeploy the app again on Netlify or is there a way to make my repo changes sync to Netlify.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect a Netlify site to GitHub such that changes to your repo are automatically pulled in and deployed. This is under "Site Settings/Build and Deploy" in your Netlify site admin.

Comment: Thank you very much Raymond. I'll try it.